# JPA CriteriaBuilder - alternative wildcard characters

Tags: jpa, wildcard, jpa-criteria

In a query like this

```
predicates.add(cb.like(fromPet.get(Pet_.name), name));
```

It accepts "%" as a replacement for any amount of characters and "_" as a replacement for any single character.

is it possible to redefine these two wildcards-characters, for example with "*" instead of "%" and "?" instead of "_"?

I am aware that I could manually trace through `pet.name` and replace the characters on my own, but I was wondering if the JPA CriteriaBuilder supports custom wildcards.

Comment: JPQL "LIKE" follows SQL "LIKE". So this only shows the behaviour of the underlying SQL datastores

Comment: No that's not possible. JPA uses SQL default wildcards.